# Remove function for Doubly Linked List c++

Tags: c++, linked-list, doubly-linked-list, dev-c++

I am trying to implement a remove function for my Doubly Linked List class.

```
#include <iostream>

#include <string>
 #include <vector>
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

 using namespace std;



 class DblLinkedBag
  {
    private:
       struct node{


       string data;
       node* next;
       node* prev; 
    }*start=NULL;

      int itemCount;  
      string item; 
      node *head;
      node *tail; 



      public:
      DblLinkedBag();
      ~DblLinkedBag();                       
      int getCurrentSize();
      bool isEmpty();
     bool add(string value);
      bool remove(string item);
     void clear();
      bool contains(string target);
     int getFrequencyOf();
    string retStart();


    string getItem();



 };
```

This is what have so far for the remove function.

```
  bool DblLinkedBag::remove(string value)

   {
   node* to_remove = head;
   while(to_remove && to_remove->data != item)
   to_remove = to_remove->next;

  // Do the removal if we found it
  if(to_remove)
  {
  // If it was at the head, advance the head to the next item
    if(to_remove == head)
   head = head->next;


   // Remove from the list
   if(to_remove->next)
   to_remove->next->prev = to_remove->prev;
   if(to_remove->prev)
   to_remove->prev->next = to_remove->next;

 // Free the removed node
 delete to_remove;
 itemCount--;
 return true;
}

return false;
```

When I try to run it, nothing happens, it doesn't even return false.  Could it possibly be because of the way I implemented my add function? Here is my add function.

```
   bool DblLinkedBag::add(string value)
   {

    node* n;
   bool add=false;
   cout<<itemCount<<endl;
   if(itemCount==0)
    {
    n=new node;
    n->data=value;
    n->prev=NULL;
    head=n;
    tail=n;
    add=true;


   }

  if(itemCount>0 && itemCount<7)
   {
    n= new node;
    n->data=value;
    n->prev=tail;
    tail->next=n;
    tail=n;
    add=true;


 }

   itemCount++;
   return add;
  }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

This is how I called the functions.

```
  void displayBag(int size)
  {  DblLinkedBag bag;

    cout << "The bag contains " <<size
    << " items:" << endl;


  int numberOfEntries = size;
  //for (int i = 0; i < numberOfEntries; i++)
  // {

    //  cout <<bagItems[i]  << " ";
    // }  // end for
  //    cout << endl << endl;

  }  // end displayBag



void copyConstructorTester()
{

      DblLinkedBag bag;
      string items[6] = {"zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five"};
      for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
      {
      cout << "Adding " << items[i] << endl;
      bag.add(items[i]);

     //    bool success = bag.add(items[i]);
       //if (!success)
      //     cout << "Failed to add " << items[i] << " to the bag." << endl;
     }


     void bagTester()
     {
     DblLinkedBag bag;
      cout << "Testing the Link-Based Bag:" << endl;
      cout << "isEmpty: returns " << bag.isEmpty()
     << "; should be 1 (true)" << endl;
    cout<<"*BAG TESTER*"<<endl;
    displayBag(bag.getCurrentSize());

    string items[] = {"one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "one"};
    cout << "Add 6 items to the bag: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
       {
       bag.add(items[i]);
      }  // end for



     displayBag(bag.getCurrentSize());
     bag.display();
     cout << "isEmpty: returns " << bag.isEmpty()
     << "; should be 0 (false)" << endl;


     cout << "getCurrentSize: returns " << bag.getCurrentSize()
     << "; should be 6" << endl;

    cout << "Try to add another entry: add(\"extra\") returns "
    << bag.add("extra") << endl;

    cout << "contains(\"three\"): returns " << bag.contains("three")
  << "; should be 1 (true)" << endl;
  // cout << "contains(\"ten\"): returns " << bag.contains("ten")
      // << "; should be 0 (false)" << endl;
   // cout << "getFrequencyOf(\"one\"): returns "
   // << bag.getFrequencyOf("one") << " should be 2" << endl;
   cout << "remove(\"one\"): returns " << bag.remove("one")
   << "; should be 1 (true)" << endl;
  // cout << "getFrequencyOf(\"one\"): returns "
   // << bag.getFrequencyOf("one") << " should be 1" << endl;
   cout << "remove(\"one\"): returns " << bag.remove("one")
    << "; should be 1 (true)" << endl;
   cout << "remove(\"one\"): returns " << bag.remove("one")
     << "; should be 0 (false)" << endl;
   // cout << endl;

    displayBag(bag.getCurrentSize());

    cout << "After clearing the bag, ";
    bag.clear();

   cout << "isEmpty: returns " << bag.isEmpty()
   << "; should be 1 (true)" << endl;
  }  // end bagTester





    int main()
   { 


   copyConstructorTester();
   bagTester();
   return 0;
 }  // end main
```

Comment: Did you step through your code using a debugger?

Comment: Did you call remove?

Comment: @Anedar no I did not

Comment: Draw a picture of 3 elements in your double linked list and their links.  Take a red pencil, and draw the links that would change when you do the removal of the item in the middle.  Check if your code does what is expected.    Iterate for the first elment supposing it's the begin of list, and the last element, if it's end of the list.

Comment: Then you should do so - it will give you a lot information about what is happening and why.

Comment: @JamesRoot I just edited the post to show how I called the fuctions.

Comment: Debugger, pencilled blocks, lines, arrows............ think!

Comment: Using StackOverflow as a debugging service is not the best use of your development time.  See your [previous post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35664224/doubly-linked-list-c-implementing-with-a-class).

Answer (score 0):

This is how you draw a doubly linked list to figure out removal of a node.

```
  Node 1  
+----------+------+------+  
| Previous | Data | Next |   
|  -0-     |  ?   |      |  
+----------+------+------+  
    ^                 |  
    |     Node 2      V  
+----------+------+------+  
| Previous | Data | Next |   
+----------+------+------+  
    ^                 |  
    |     Node 3      V  
+----------+------+------+  
| Previous | Data | Next |   
|          |  ?   |  -0- |  
+----------+------+------+
```

Let's assume the following pointers:

```
Node * node1 = head;
Node * node2(node1->next);
Node * node3(node2->next);
```

One possiblity is to start with the *previous* links:
Make Node 3's previous link point to Node 1:

```
  node3->previous = node1;  

  Node 1  
+----------+------+------+  
| Previous | Data | Next |   
|  -0-     |  ?   |      |  
+----------+------+------+  
   ^   ^              |  
   |   |              |
+--+   |              |    
|      |     Node 2   V  
|   +------+------+------+  
|   | Prev | Data | Next |   
|   +------+------+------+  
|                     |  
+---+                 |  
    |     Node 3      V  
+----------+------+------+  
| Previous | Data | Next |   
|          |  ?   |  -0- |  
+----------+------+------+
```

The next step is to make the `Next` link of `Node 1` point to Node 3:
`node1->next = node3;`

```
 Node 1  
+----------+------+------+  
| Previous | Data | Next |   
|  -0-     |  ?   |      |  
+----------+------+------+  
   ^   ^              |  
   |   |              |
+--+   |              +------+   
|      |     Node 2          |
|   +------+------+------+   |  
|   | Prev | Data | Next |   |   
|   +------+------+------+   |  
|                   |        |  
|                   |  +-----+  
+---+               |  |   
    |     Node 3    V  V  
+----------+------+------+  
| Previous | Data | Next |   
|          |  ?   |  -0- |  
+----------+------+------+
```

In the above diagram, as you trace the links from `Node 1` to `Node 3` and `Node 3` to `Node 1`, you will notice that `Node 2` was not accessed.

Thus `Node 2` can safely be removed.

And finally, delete node 2

```
delete node2;
```

In summary:

```
Node * current = head;
Node * previous = head;

// Find the node
while (current->data != key)
{
    previous = current;
    current = current->next;
}

// Assume node was found.
Node after = current->next;

// Make previous point to the node after the current.
previous->next = after;

// Make the node after the current node point to the previous.
if (after != NULL)
{
  after->previous = previous;
}

// Delete the current node.
delete current;
```